# Discrepancy in results using Python datetime.timedelta

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

I'm new to Python. I am having a wrong datetime calculation in my .py file, the line goes like this:

```
tt = ref_time + datetime.timedelta(seconds=(60*work_start_time))
```

with work_start_time equals a positive value (minutes), tt turns out going backward time. I tried to find the error origin, so I print the input variables before this line:

```
print 'work_start_time=',work_start_time
print 'ref_time=',ref_time
print datetime.timedelta(seconds=(60*work_start_time))
tt = ref_time + datetime.timedelta(seconds=(60*work_start_time))
print 'tt=',tt
```

the printed result is:

```
work_start_time= 780
ref_time= 2014-01-01 00:00:00
-1 day, 23:52:35.359744
tt= 2013-12-31 23:52:35.359744
```

Clearly, this datetime.timedelta gives me totally wrong answer, how could a positive 780 minutes turned out to be a negative 7 seconds? Then I tried these lines directly in the python console, then the calculation is correct with

```
tt= 2014-01-01 13:00:00
```

Might it be some problem with my .py file? work_start_time is an output of some other functions in my .py file. But the value of work_start_time is really 780 at this line. The ref_time is assigned at the beginning of this file as:

```
ref_time = datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 1, 0, 0)
```

And the file runs all right with no errors pumping out.

Please help me! I'm totally stuck. Thanks a lot!

Comment: what are the values of work_start_time, ref_time?

Comment: @hagubear I'd say `780` and `2014-01-01 00:00:00`, respectively. As shown.

Comment: No you said "The result is.....". I will edit the body

Comment: @Alice, I don't think it will help, but `datetime.timedelta(minutes=work_start_time)` looks better...

Comment: Did you know that `timedelta()` takes a `minutes` argument? No need to multiply anything by 60 here.

Comment: thanks Martijn and glglgl, ok, I'll try timedelta with minutes and see...

Comment: Well, tried minutes, no help with this problem, same output.  thanks anyway!

Comment: Can you include your assignment of `ref_time` in your code please? so we can try and reproduce your problem? As it is, your code does not reproduce the problem you describe.

Comment: @hagubear, sorry if my post confused you. I said 'the result is' really means 'the printed result', so at that line work_start_time=780, ref_time=2014-01-01 00:00:00

Comment: @khelwood, included, it's just a simple assignment. Yes I tried these lines in my console which also has no problem. I guess there is something with my .py file..

Comment: Oh Guys, I think I found the problem, if I define work_start_time as np.int32 in the console, then run the datetime.timedelta will produce the same wrong calculation. if I change work_start_time as np.int, then the problem is gone. however np.int64 will produce an error. Anyone could explain the reason?

Comment: @Alice: that's a huge distinction; `np.int32` is not a type `datetime` supports. What you got is an overflow and `datetime` sees it as a signed integer. Pass in *standard `int()` objects*.

Comment: @Alice: on Python 2.7, when I try to pass in numpy integers I get `TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta minutes component: numpy.int32`. Interestingly enough `numpy.int32(780)*60` gives me a plain Python integer, so there is more to your value here than meets the eye. Had you printed out `work_start_time * 60` you'd perhaps have seen this earlier.